# Benchmarks for Single and MultiThreaded programs

Tags: java, performance, multithreading, concurrency, benchmarking

I am trying to compare the performance of Single and Multithreaded Java programs. Are there any single thread benchmarks which are available which I could then use and convert to their multithreaded version and compare the performance. Could anybody guide me as to what kind of programs(not very small) are suitable for this empirical comparison.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JUnit](http://junit.sourceforge.net/) with something like [JUnitBenchmarks](http://labs.carrotsearch.com/junit-benchmarks.html).